# Python- Trying to find a date in a list

Tags: python

I have a txt file that contains all the dates in a year in mm/dd/yy format.
01/01/20
01/02/20
01/03/20
01/04/20
01/05/20
01/06/20

And I have a today's date from Python code:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
date = current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

When I try to find the list element == date i don't get a match. The code is:

```
for i in range(0,366):
    if(date==calendarData[i]):
        break
else:
    print(i,end="  ")
    print("date", date, end=" ")
    print(calendarData[i], end="")
    i=i+1
```

From the console

```
269  date 09/29/2020  0 9 / 2 6 / 2 0
270  date 09/29/2020  0 9 / 2 7 / 2 0
271  date 09/29/2020  0 9 / 2 8 / 2 0
272  date 09/29/2020  0 9 / 2 9 / 2 0
273  date 09/29/2020  0 9 / 3 0 / 2 0
274  date 09/29/2020  1 0 / 0 1 / 2 0
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your `calendarData` array to datetime objects?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the fact that you get spaced out dates like `0 9 / 2 6 / 2 0` in your output explain why your expression `date==calendarData[i]` is never true?

Comment: They're not even the same length, let alone identical strings.  How do you expect them to compare as equal?

Answer (score 0):

In your print, you can see that the dates you have in the .txt file have spaces between the numbers "0 9 / 2 9 / 2 0", try getting rid of the spaces, try:

```
if(date==calendarData[i].replace(" ", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spacing issue to me.

```
calendarData[i].replace(' ','')
```

should remove the extra whitespaces from the dates from your file.

Comment: Thanks for the input. .replace didn't work, however; changing the encription to ANSI did the trick.